# Domain Rewrite for both HTTP and HTTPS in IIS 7

Tags: redirect, iis-7, web-config, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I want to do a number of `301` redirects in one request and I found [this article](https://moz.com/blog/what-every-seo-should-know-about-iis#chaining) to be helpful. However, I have a problem where `http://example.com` redirects to `https://www.example.com` BUT `https://example.com` DOES NOT redirect to `https://www.example.com`

So here are my examples:

1. SEO - remove default.aspx (works fine but no HTTPS)
   https://www.example.com/app/default.aspx => https://www.example.com/app/

BUT http://www.example.com/app/default.aspx => http://www.example.com/app/

2. SEO - Remove trailing slash (doesn't work and no HTTPS as above)
   All links get the trailing slash instead
   http://www.example.com/app => http://www.example.com/app/
   https://www.example.com/app => https://www.example.com/app/
3. SEO - ToLower (works fine but no HTTPS as above)
   http://www.example.com/APP => http://www.example.com/app
   https://www.example.com/APP => https://www.example.com/app
4. SEO - http canonical redirect (works 100%)
   http://example.com/app => https://www.example.com/app
5. SEO - https canonical redirect (doesn't work at all)
   https://example.com/app => https://www.example.com/app - ***FAILS***
6. SEO - non-canonical redirect (Doesn't work 100%. Without this rule the stylesheet fails to load, but also other links that didn't match any of the above are not being )
   https://example.com/app => https://example.com/app/
   http://example.com/app => http://example/com/app/
   https://www.example.com/app => https://www.example.com/app/
   http://www.example.com/app => http://www.example.com/app/

This is what I have implemented and the problem is as above.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="WhiteList - resources" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^resources/" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SEO - remove default.aspx" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="(.*?)/?default\.aspx$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="_{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SEO - Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="(.+)/$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="_{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SEO - ToLower" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
                <add input="{R:1}" pattern="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="_{ToLower:{R:1}}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SEO - http canonical redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(_*)(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SEO - https canonical redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(_*)(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SEO - non-canonical redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(_+)(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}" />
        </rule>         
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Consider adding a ignoreCase="true" after the https condition: <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" ignoreCase="true" />

Comment: Unfortunately Tony that didn't help. I tried it this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a solution as I found the actual problem with IIS.

When you visit https://example.com with the rules above setup (or https canonical redirect) it will first give you a certificate error if you don't have the "naked domain" certification. If the user opt to continue, then the redirect to https://www.example.com will happen.

I think this may be happening at the "DNS Negotiation" level rather than IIS level.

Comment: just add a mapping to the naked domain (port 443) with any certificate, then redirect the correct www domain web.config

the user will not receive a wrong certificate error, since the browser will redirect to the correct url before opening the page.